# How to check a particular key exists in JSON response using Retrofit Library

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am getting some JSON values from the server but I don't know if there will be a particular field or not.I need to validate based on the key .

**One Type Of Response**

[image]

**Another Type Of Response**[image]

In AysncTask we can use "has" function but in Retrofit i am unable to find a solution .

Provide me a solution

Comment: Please add the code from your Retrofit interface and say whether you are using any `ConverterFactory` (ie GSON)

Comment: @Jahnold - In datas i get all the data, can u say me how to validate if the response has "reviewer_details" key

Comment: @Jahnold - When i use AysncTask i validate like **has("reviewer_details")** . When i am using retrofit **response.body().getDatas()** and how should i validate

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: @SushobhNadiger , for AysncTask you can do like this JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        if(jsonObject.has("reviewer_details")){
          //do process with data
        }            but when i am using retrofit  i unable to use has function ,

Answer (score 3):

Retrofit will parse all attributes that you specified in your model. If some attribute in your JSON does not exist **Retrofit will set NULL as the value of that attribute**.

Knowing this feature, the only thing that you need to do is something like:

```
if(myObject.getReviewerDetails() == null)  
 // do something
```

Happy code!

Answer (score 1):

You can check key exist or not using jsonObject.has like following way,

```
      JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        if(jsonObject.has("reviewer_details")){
          //do process with data
        }
```

Comment: If i am using AsyncTask , the above solution will solve. I am using **Retrofit Library** to parse the JSON response, so  kindly provide me a solution using Retrofit.